# Add the post title to php code

Tags: php, wordpress, web-scraping

Im using the wordpress plugin [WP Web Scraper](http://wp-ws.net/) and i want to pull the current stock price of apple from yahoo.

So this is basically how you do it. But this is not how I want to do it.

```
<?php echo wpws_get_content("http://finance.yahoo.com/q;_ylt=AubbkdWzK3JVgeeOxVZvOwmQJ7gB;_ylc=X1MDMjE0MjQ3ODk0OARfcgMyBGZyA3VoM19maW5hbmNlX3dlYl9nc19jdHJsMQRmcjIDc2EtZ3AEZ3ByaWQDBG5fZ3BzAzEwBG9yaWdpbgNmaW5hbmNlLnlhaG9vLmNvbQRwb3MDMgRwcXN0cgMEcXVlcnkDQUFQTCwEc2FjAzEEc2FvAzE-?p=http%3A%2F%2Ffinance.yahoo.com%2Fq%3Fs%3DAAPL%26ql%3D0&uhb=uhb2&fr=uh3_finance_vert_gs_ctrl1&s=AAPL", "span.time_rtq_ticker", array('output' => 'text')); ?>
```

This way I have to manually add AAPL to the s=AAPL part. I've named my post title AAPL so how can I make it so it automatically add my post title to the s= part?

I have tried a few things like `s=<?php the_title(); ?>` and `s=" . $the_title . "` but this doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `s=<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>`

Comment: @KaushaMehta no luck, comes back as  Error parsing: Query returned empty response

Comment: Please add you query in detail. And add your full code from where you want. What is you tried and what error cames.

Comment: @KaushaMehta I want to grab the AAPL stock price from yahoo finance, but it must use my post title so I dont have to manually add AAPL to the s= part. So my post title will be AAPL and it will add that to the s=

Comment: Ok, First try `<?php echo get_the_title(); die(); ?> inside loop and let me know what is output.

Comment: @KaushaMehta again i got  Error parsing: Query returned empty response

Comment: That means you are not getting the post title there, if you add you whole code then i can help you out.

Comment: @KaushaMehta i've added the whole code...